# Цикл for и разновидность

Tags: java

Друзья! Нашел такой цикл в книге:

```
public class For {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        num = 100;

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (i * i >= num)
                break;
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("Цикл завершен");
    }
}
```

Я знаю что фигурные скобки опускаются и без них всё может работать правильно, но это считается плохим тоном.

Далее переделал:

```
public class For {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        num = 100;

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (i * i >= num) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("Цикл завершен");
    }
}
```

И это стало правильным вариантом с фигурными скобками.

Но почему когда я делаю вот так:

```
public class For {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        num = 100;

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (i * i >= num) {
                break;
                System.out.print(i + " "); // выдается ошибка: unreachable statement
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Цикл завершен");
    }
}
```

Не пойму что за ошибка и почему я не могу `System.out.println()` написать внутри цикла if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предупреждение `unreachable statement` говорит о том, что `System.out.print(i + " ");` никогда не будет вызвано, из-за `break`.

Цикл в этом месте просто прервется.